# Isn't any algebra with finite composition length and non-isomorphic simple modules semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

Assume $A$ is an algebra over a field $K$ with composition length $n$ and $A$ has $n$ pairwise non-isomorphic simple modules. Is it true that this implies that $A$ is semisimple?

The answer seems to be "Yes" (see the proof below), but I wonder whether my proof is correct because the proof seems to be quite simple but the exercise 4.14 in [Erdmann, Holm's "Algebras and Representation Theory"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Algebras_and_Representation_Theory.html?id=iVptDwAAQBAJ) ([pdf](http://math0.bnu.edu.cn/%7Eliuym/Book-algebras-and-representations.pdf)) is similar to the above statement with the additional requirements that $A$ is commutative and $n$-dimensional.

> Assume $A$ is a commutative $K$-algebra of dimension $n$. Show that if
> $A$ has $n$ pairwise non-isomorphic simple modules then $A$ must be
> semisimple.

If the proof is indeed correct, that would mean that the condition "commutative" is unnecessary and "dimension $n$" can be relaxed to "composition length $n$", and then it is unclear why these additional conditions were picked in the wording of the exercise.

---

Proof: Assume the contrary. Since $A$ is not semisimple but has finite composition length, Theorem 4.23 implies that $J(A) \neq 0$ and $J(A) \neq J^2(A)$. Pick maximal proper left sub-ideal of $J(A)$ containing $J^2(A)$: $J(A) \supset M \supseteq J^2(A)$ and an element $b \in J(A) \setminus M$. Consider an $A$-module homomorphism
$$\varphi: A / J(A) \to J(A) / M: a + J(A) \mapsto ab + M.$$
It is well-defined since if $a \in J(A)$ then $ab \in J(A)^2 \subseteq M$. We claim that $\varphi = 0$. From Theorem 4.23 we know that the module $A/J(A)$ is semisimple, hence it can be written (up to isomorphism) as $S_1\oplus \dots \oplus S_{k}$ for some simple modules $S_j$. From the assumption all components in the composition series of
$A$ are pairwise non-isomorphic. In particular, $S_j$ is not isomorphic to $J(A)/M$. Therefore, from Schur's lemma we know that $\varphi$ restricted to $S_j$ is $0$. Since this is true for every $j$, $\varphi = 0$. This, however, contradicts with $\varphi(1_{A} + J(A)) = a + M \neq 0$. $\square$

Comment: Where in your proof are you using that $A$ has $n$ non-isomorphic simple modules and at the same time length $n$? So far, it looks like you are proving that no algebra of finite length can have non-zero Jacobson radical, which is clearly false.

Comment: @Pedro 1. Theorem 4.23 from the textbook, which is used twice in my proof, applies only to algebras of finite composition length. 2. $A$ has $n$ factors $V_j / V_{j-1}$ in its composition series and we know that all simple $A$-modules are of this form (Theorem 3.19 from the textbook). Hence, from the assumption, all of them are pairwise non-isomorphic and, in particular, simple submodules of $A/J(A)$ are not isomorphic to $J(A)/M$, which we are using to show $\varphi = 0$.

Comment: @Pedro I've modified the proof to make it clearer.

Comment: You are assuming that every simple occurs precisely once in a composition series for $A$. Since every simple also occurs in $A/J(A)$, this implies that $A$ is semisimple. You are correct that this does not require commutativity.